# How to use regex to find exact match of a word but ignoring the same text with preposition? C#

Tags: c#, regex

hi i've been working with DXF files and i got some trouble for regular expression.
i have some text like this

```
   BODY
   123
   abc
   GR-BODY
   attrib
   AcdbLine
```

and i've write some regular expression that should be work but clearly i still need some help for this regular expression

here is my code

```
string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"(3DFACE|3DSOLID|ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT|LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADERSTYLE|MLEADER|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE|LINE)", RegexOptions.None);
```

and i would like just to catch the BODY text but the GR-BODY still included, how to exclude the GR-BODY?
thanks

EDIT 1
i'm sorry i look for the wrong code earlier

umm i want to the output like this

```
tmp[0] = BODY
tmp[1] = 123\nabc\nGR-LINE\nattrib\nAcdbLine
```

since my code only been able to make it like this

```
tmp[0] = BODY
tmp[1] = 123\nabc\nGR-
tmp[2] = BODY\nattrib\nAcdbLine
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How should the result look like?

Comment: Do you mean you want this as your output?

tmp[1] = 123\nabc\nGR-BODY\nattrib\nAcdbLine

Answer (score 1):

That regex statement should work. Try using **Regex.Matches** to return a **MatchCollection** instead.

```
   MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(originalString, @"(3DFACE|3DSOLID|ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT|LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADERSTYLE|MLEADER|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE|LINE)", RegexOptions.None);
   string[] tmp = mc.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: hmm is there some way to edit my code to split it? because i need the regex word to be included in the output

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to the matches to output GR-LINE if that is in the original string, or you want it to only output LINE from GR-LINE?

Comment: ah misha i'm sorry please look for my question again, it's my mistake the problem with is with the BODY

Answer (score 0):

If your words are always from the start to the end of the row, then tell the pattern this:

```
string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"^(3DFACE|3DSOLID|ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT|LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADERSTYLE|MLEADER|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE|LINE)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This should give you the output you expect.

`^` Matches the **start** of the row when the `Multiline` option is used

`$` Matches the **end** of the row when the `Multiline` option is used